# Drop down menu is not displayed correctly in the navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap 4

I created a navbar with a drop menu section.

Demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/hja1dj2j/3/

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span>admin</span>
                        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">

          <a href="/menu/changepassword" class="dropdown-item" role="menuitem">Changer de mot de passe</a>

          <a href="javascript: document.logoutForm.submit()" class="dropdown-item" role="menuitem">Déconnexion</a>
          <form name="logoutForm" action="/logout" method="post" hidden="hidden">
            <input hidden type="submit" value="Sign Out" />
          </form>

        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Image of the issue
[image: nav-bar_drop-down-menu]

When I click on the drop down menu, we can see is not displayed correctly.

Any idea?

Comment: Your resource link to Bootstrap's JS is: `ttps://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js` ... you forgot an 'h'

Comment: ok I updated but that don't fix the issue.

Comment: What you are seeing is not a bug/incorrect display. Drop down menus operate by default left-to-right.  For right-aligned items you need to add additional class names to force the Drop Right variation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#dropright-variation